# Germanic vs. Germaic

Tags: meaning, word-usage, errors

My son was just describing something as being *germaic* and I corrected him to say *germanic*, at which point he pulled up *germaic* on the internet.

Is there any reason to use **germaic** instead of **germanic**?

Comment: Where did he cite "germaic" from? A reliable source or just some random post online? Can you please provide more information to the post?

Comment: Germanic with a capital G by the way, means from German or related to the Germanic peoples. Germaic looks like a typo to me.

Comment: from 20th century... https://www.google.co.uk/#q=germaic&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1900,cd_max:1999 but a number are misreadings

Comment: "Germanic" is an adjective derived from the base "German". "Germaic" would only be expected if you were deriving an adjective from a base like "Germa" (compare "formulaic" from "formula", "algebraic" from "algebra").

Comment: It's an error. It's kinda crazy but typos happen on the internet and don't get fixed.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about a typo

Comment: @FumbleFingers A question about a typo in a particular text is off-topic because it's of no interest to anybody but the person who is trying to understand the text. But a question about a common misspelling may be useful to many future visitors.

Comment: @MetaEd♦: I don't believe you can credibly label it either "common" or a "misspelling". Your Google search link produces just 1750 hits, compared to ***About 14,600,000 results*** for the search term it suggests you *should* have been looking for.

Comment: @MetaEd It should certainly be closed for lack of research.

Comment: By analogy with existing words, "germaic" would mean "pertaining to" "germa", "germees", or "germay".

Comment: *at which point he pulled up germaic on the internet* One more reason not to have children.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A Google search for [ ["germaic" "germanic"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22germaic%22+%22germanic%22) ] will turn up many examples of this common typographical error. Here are some.

## 1

“[The development of voiced labiovelars in Germanic](http://folk.uio.no/sverrej/talk_files/2008/november/ucla/johnsen.november.2008.ucla.pdf)”<sup>[PDF]</sup> from the website *[Sverre Stausland Johnsen](http://folk.uio.no/sverrej/)* (University of Oslo):

> Cubbin, G. P. 1979. A case of homonymic clash in ***Germaic**. *IF* 84:226‐236.

*[actual title of cited article is verifiably “A case of homonymic clash in **Germanic**”]*

## 2

“[The Pronunciation of Smaug](http://www.arrantpedantry.com/2013/12/20/the-pronunciation-of-smaug/)” from the website *[Arrant Pedantry](http://www.arrantpedantry.com/)*:

> this shows Smugan as an Old English word, derived from the Proto-***Germaic**

*[article is tagged *Proto-**Germanic***]*

## 3

“[Lecture by Janet Swaffar, September 22, 2006](http://blc.berkeley.edu/2006/09/22/lecture_september_22_2006_janet_swaffar/)” from the website *[Berkeley Language Center](http://blc.berkeley.edu/)*:

> “Some Thoughts on the Cultural Permutations of Literacy in Language Teaching”
>   by Janet Swaffar, Professor of German, Department of ***Germaic** Studies, University of Texas at Austin

*[actual department name is verifiably ***Germanic*** Studies*]

## Note

In the examples, **bold face** emphasis is mine, and asterisk (*) indicates wrong spelling.

Comment: Google: Committed to spreading catachresis across all the wide, wide world.

Comment: It pleases me to no end to see something proven as a typo.